# microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser won't show video clips

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

In my Windows Phone application I'm loading a html site into a view, really simple stuff with this method:

```
var itemView = view as NorwegianBrowserView;
var webBrowser = itemView.browserContainer;
webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(_globalAccessObjects.ActiveNorwayLink,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

The site loads everything except a video clip. Or well it knows the video is there but it just shows a black square. And pressing that black square does nothing.

As i side note i can add that i got the same application for iOS and Android and they both got no problem in loading the very same website(+ they load the video). And here i can press the video clip and it will start playing.

Am i loading the website into my view the wrong way? or does microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser not support a video clip?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to play video clips in line in a web page is dependent upon the version of Windows Phone you are running on and the format of the video.

Only Window Phone 8.1 supports playing video within a page. Unfortunately this isn't yet widely available.
Even then the video format may still be an issue and if not supported could lead to a placeholder image being displayed.

Comment: I'm testing it on a windows 8.1 running the latest version. I'm not sure what format the video is.

Comment: I just created a new WP8.0 app, added this XAML: `<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="MyBrowser" IsScriptEnabled="True" />` and then in the main page constructor called `this.MyBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/"));` and was able to watch the videos in the browser on an 8.1 device. Without the specifics of your scenario it's going to be hard to say what's wrong for you.

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks for your insight. At least it gave me the guts to keep trying:)